# Bruises lasting effect

Tags: dermatology

Grappling every day and getting repeat bruises. Will this decrease the skin's softness or cause it to age faster or lose its elasticity?

The bruises are caused by

- pinching
- the skin getting pressed against their skin and pulled apart. So the opposite of pinching.
- force like being hit or pressed hard

Comment: Thank you for your post :) I edited , because questions asking for personal advice or diagnosis are not allowed on the site as no one can answer them as best as your doctor usually. It was just a minor edit, feel free to rollback if you don't like it or even re edit. Thank you!